# image and text not displaying center in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below code logo and text was not displaying. when I am adding the style to vertical-align:center.I want image and text should me center

Any one help me

```css
.logo{
  
  display:inline-block;
}
.logo a {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
}
.logo a img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.logo p {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo_sml.jpg"></a>
      <p>Newton Public School<br>
   Kanaka Nagar-Rt Nagar<br>
   Reach Out, Reach High, Reach Beyond</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: you want both vertical and horizontal align?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/gcLqo78m/

Answer (score 0):

Update log class like this:

```
  .logo{
       text-align: center;
       display:inline-block;
       width:100%;
  }
```

Comment: inline displays cannot be centered vertically!

Comment: You want it horizontally center or vertically middle?

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal align change `logo` style to:

```
.logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And HTML to:

```
<div class="logo">
    <p><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo_sml.jpg"></a></p>
    <p>Newton Public School<br>
    Kanaka Nagar-Rt Nagar<br>
    Reach Out, Reach High, Reach Beyond</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to center the div **only** horizontally, simply put the `.logo` div inside a center element, like this: `<center><div class="logo">...</div></center>`.
- If you want to center it **both** horizontally and vertically, try out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6182661) of a very old question.

Answer (score 0):

**Modify it**

```css
.logo{
       text-align: center;
       display:inline-block;
       width:100%;
  }
.logo a {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  padding-left: 50%;
}
.logo a img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.logo p {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo_sml.jpg"></a>
      <p>Newton Public School<br>
   Kanaka Nagar-Rt Nagar<br>
   Reach Out, Reach High, Reach Beyond</p>
      </div>
```